# Can't configure the Android Spellchecker service to simply validate if string is a valid word or not

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, spell-checking

I am building a Flutter app that requires that I validate if a string is a valid word. The user is not inputting text, he is using elements to build the word. So I just need a routine that returns true for a valid word, false if not.

I am using an [invokeMethod](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel/invokeMethod.html) call to use a native function to do this validation. For iOS I use UITextChecker that works perfectly well for this.

I 've read about the [Android SpellChecker Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/textservice/SpellCheckerService) but unfortunately all the examples I see are for adding an interaction to the user so that word suggestions are visible to the user typing text.

Can someone point to a valid Kotlin routine that justs validates words using this SpellChecker service?